# How to distinguish between mouse click and .click() in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

In javascript/jquery, I have a button that have a click event defined like:

```
$("#target").click(function() {
    var mouse_click = ________________;
    // do stuff
    if (mouse_click) {
        // do stuff  
    }
    // do stuff
});
```

and I also have code to do

```
$('#target').click();
```

How can I get the variable `mouse_click` to be `true`, if the user manually clicked the tag using the mouse, and the variable to be `false` when I click the tag using the `.click()` function?

Thanks

Comment: thanks, I just went with the answer from the duplicate, and it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this:

```
$("#target").click(function(e) {
    var mouse_click = !(e.originalEvent === undefined);
    // do stuff
    if (mouse_click) {
        // do stuff  
    }
    // do stuff
});
```

or you could check `e.isTrigger` which is set whenever an event is triggered within jQuery. You'd just need to change the second line to:

```
var mouse_click = !e.isTrigger;
```

Both will work but you might prefer the second option as it's a little more concise.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/2U3Us/4/

Comment: Is there a reason to use the `? :` operator here?  I know JS occasionally does weird conversions, but I'd lean toward the simpler `!(e.originalEvent === undefined)` and `!e.isTrigger`, myself.

Comment: @XavierHolt - good point, it must have slipped my mind. I've just updated my answer and fiddle.